# Hitting time is a stopping time

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Can somebody help me proving that the following hitting time is a stopping time?
Let $\{X_t\}_{t\ge 0}$ be a real-valued, right-continuous process, adapted to a filtration $\mathfrak{F}$ which satisfies the usual conditions. Then the hitting time $$\tau(\omega):=\inf\{t\ge 0: X_t(\omega)\ge a\}$$ is a stopping time ($a\in\mathbb{R}$ is fixed in advance).

EDIT: @AlexR, you're right, I should be a bit more precise.
The $\textit{usual conditions}$ concerning the filtration $\mathfrak{F}$ imply that it each $\sigma$-algebra in this filtration is complete (i.e. all $\mathbb{P}$-null sets are contained in it). Moreover, the filtration is right-continuous, i.e. for $t\ge 0$, it holds $\mathfrak{F}_t=\bigcap_{s>t}\mathfrak{F}_s$.

My thoughts so far: Let $t\ge 0$ and assume $\tau(\omega)\ge t$. This is equivalent to $X_s(\omega)<a$ for all $s\in[0,t)$. By right-continuity of $X$, we know that $X_s=\lim_{u\downarrow s}X_u$ for all $s\ge 0$. Hence, $X_s(\omega)<a$ is equivalent to the existence of some $\varepsilon>0$ such that $X_u(\omega)<a$ for all $u\in[s,s+\varepsilon]$; this holds for all $s\in[0,t)$, as mentioned above. Thus, we conclude:
$$\{\tau<t\}=\bigcup_{s\in[0,t)}\bigcap_{\varepsilon>0}\bigcup_{s\in[t,t+\varepsilon]}\{X_s\ge a\}.$$
Here, I get stuck: Why is this set in $\mathfrak{F}_t$ (this would be sufficient due to the usual conditions)?
Does someone see why this is the case or does someone have another ansatz to this problem?

Comment: You should (a) add the _usual conditions_ and (b) include your own thoughts to get a better chance of this not being closed.

Comment: I have added my ansatz and some further information.

Comment: That's much better now :)

Comment: Use section theorem.

Comment: @Danielsen What is the section theorem?

Comment: http://arxiv.org/abs/1001.3619 Theorem 2.7 of this paper is what you want.

Comment: Ok, but what about my ansatz (or possibly another elemetary one)? Do we really need something deep like a debut theorem?

Comment: http://planetmath.org/hittingtimesarestoppingtimes has a nice discussion of the proof for various cases. For continuous processes, this is easy to show but for right-continuous processes it seems the proof is more involved.